# C++ write a function to print all divisors of a float

Tags: c++

So I have been trying to write this function and implement it without luck. The function has to be written as `void divisor (float x )` and it will ask a user for a `int` number and run until the user inputs a value of  0 . I get a few errors one which concerns me the most is  invalid operands of types ‘float’ and ‘int ’ to binary ‘operator

I have tried writing it so:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;

void divisor (float x )
  { 
     int result ;
     int a ; 
     result =   x % a << endl ; 
     a++ 
     return 0 ; 
  }  
    };
      
 int main () 
{   int n ;
    float arg; 
    cin >> arg ;
    cin >> n ; 
    cin >> arg; 
    if    ( n =! 0 ){ 
    divisor ( arg) ;
        }else{
          cin >> n ;
      } return 0 ; 
    } ;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I fixed the code-fence problems in your post but I am reluctant to change the *actual* code. There are problems with indentation and at least one "typo" (missing `;` after `a++`). Maybe you would like to revisit the "Edit" button and address these issues.

Comment: `result =   x % a << endl ;` means "assign the value of `x % a << endl` to the variable `result`. It looks like you need [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or, if you've got one, reviewing the first chapter or two.

Comment: What is a divisor of a float? What are the divisors of 2.5? 0.5 and 5? 0.00001 and 250000?

Comment: Given the value (precision) change when converting from decimal to binary (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken ) I don't think this question has an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `x % a` is only valid for integral types `x` and `a`. Since `x` is a `float` type, compilation fails.

If you want the floating point modulus for a `float` type, then use

```
std::fmodf
```

instead. (Note that `a` will be implicitly converted to a `float`.)

Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod

Comment: even with `fmodf` I don't understand how to find divisors of a `float`, because `std::fmodf( x,y) == 0` requires a bit of "luck" to get `true`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818: I don't think IEEE754 offers any guarantees. But I would regard any implementation of `fmodf` that doesn't return the best `float` possible back to be defective.

Comment: what I mean is: OP seems to be looking for `int` divisors of `float`s, but only integers have integer divisors

Comment: what you wrote isnt wrong, but the question needs clarification. There is more wrong with the code (eg what is the role of `a` supposed to be in `divisor`)